# Package.json fields: Child directories are not ignored

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working on a large TS-based library. When I build the application, this creates a lot of `.d.ts` files, most of which are of internal use only, and make no sense to export or ship to the end user. Usually I've used a `.npmignore` file to keep these out, but recently learned that certain tools really prefer that information to be included via the `"files"` field of the `package.json`, so here I am trying to convert.

Now, I have a directory structure that looks somewhat like this:

```
dist/
--bundle.js
--...
--components/
----componentA.d.ts
----componentB.d.ts
----common/
----...
--hooks/
----...
--util/
----...
```

The idea is that I want all top level files, and all files directly under `/components/` but no child directories. In my `.npmignore`, I'd do this like:

```
# blacklist all
**

# include whitelist
!dist/*
!dist/components/*
```

However, when I do the same under `"files"` in my `package.json`, all that crap still comes along. The single wildcard is not respected.

Edit:

```
"files": [
    "dist/*",
    "dist/components/*",
    ...
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducing what you show of your file system, this works for me:

```json
  "files": ["dist/*.js", "dist/components/*.ts"]
```

Omitting the file extensions indeed included all the subdirectory cruft. I tested with npm 7 and npm 6.